# run a matlab script on a remote server

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, remote-access, matlab-compiler

I have ssh access to a remote linux server and no admin rights. The server does not have matlab installed and I need to run a few matlab scripts. Are there any ways by which I can run these scripts on the server ? I read a few links saying to download the matlab compiler or runtime but they do not have detailed instructions on how to proceed and even less so pertaining to remote servers.

Comment: Use MATLAB Compiler to create a distributable

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Could you please share some more information on the steps to be followed or cite a link where I can get more information. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This should be a good start https://mathworks.com/help/compiler/create-and-install-a-standalone-application-from-matlab-code.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally there are three options

1. install MATLAB (it is available for Linux but you need to have admin rights..)
2. box your scripts as distributables with the [*Application Compiler*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/deployment-process.html) (as @UnbearableLigthness already mentioned). You will need to install the MATLAB Runtime on your Linux server to run those applications. However, [you can package the runtime in the application](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/create-and-install-a-standalone-application-from-matlab-code.html#mw_b5937144-282c-4954-a943-c16851fbfdb6) (bulletpoint 3).
3. create C code with the [*MATLAB Coder*](https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/the-joy-of-generating-c-code-from-matlab.html) and compile it on your Linux server. This requires no installation but does not support all functions (e.g. most constrained optimization algorithms are not supported)

Comment: I think your second point isn't completely correct. I'm fairly certain one can choose to package the runtime within the executable.

Comment: ah yes, you are right @UnbearableLightness. This will increase the application size but is irrelevant if you have only one application running there anyway. You probably not even need rights to install this as it can be linked relative to the package =)

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it because it simplifies the workflow significantly.